# Why are colors described as pointers in Java?

Tags: java, colors

In any of my Java programs I use an integer array for the pixels color values. I then use the Graphics and buffering included libraries to draw these to the screen. In the loop I use to populate the pixel array I use a pointer (this is knowledge I adopted from various tutorials) such as 0xffffff for white. From my understanding, a pointer is just directions to memory allocations. Why does this work? I may just have a vague understanding of pointers but it doesn't quite make sense to me that a direction to some memory would be a color. Could someone please help to enlighten me on why is occurs so that I could potentially use this knowledge in other applications (or languages)?

Comment: 0xffffff is an integer value compacting three 0-255 values Red, Green, Blue. The class Color is an abstraction handling components etc.

Comment: That's not a pointer. Being hexadecimal doesn't mean it's a memory address. Hexadecimal is just another way of writing a number value.

Comment: I was for some reason under the impression that the "0x" preceding the hex value was a declaration of a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

0xffffff is not a pointer but an integer value represented as a hexadecimal string. It specifies the rgb value:

- red: ff = 255
- green: ff = 255
- blue: ff = 255

Answer (score 1):

White being represented as 0xffffff is simply a hexadecimal presentation of the integer RBG (red/green/blue) values used to make up that color. It has nothing to do with pointers.

You are confusing the fact that usually pointer addresses are shown in hex.

Answer (score 0):

It is only coincidence.

Standard color on your screen is created from 3 base colors : red, green, blue.

Each of them can have 256 variants, its 8-bit, thats why it is called 24-bit.

0xffffff is divided into : ff x ff x ff, each one shows value for that 3 base colors.

FF is in 16-base, F=15 and FF=255